# Довіреність чи доручення на укладання угод

Tags: вживання-слів

Є такий ноторіальний документ, що дозволяє одній людині діяти від імені іншої, включно з правом підпису та укладання угод. Наприклад, можна дозволити комусь пере-укласти угоди з комунальними підпріємствами після купівлі нового житла.

Якому терміну варто надавати перевагу у цьому контексті?

Обидва слова мають відповідні значення згідно СУМу

> [**ДОРУ́ЧЕННЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/DORUChENNJa), я, сер.
>
> 2. Документ, що дає кому-небудь право діяти від імені особи, що видала цей документ; довіреність. Турбай попросив рахунок і в лівому кутку
>      вписав доручення на ім'я Лариси (Микола Руденко, Остання шабля, 1959,
>      572); Він лише попросив, щоб йому виплатити всі гроші, зароблені в
>      колгоспі, за дорученням, яке він дасть Кіндратові Горенку (Василь
>      Кучер, Трудна любов, 1960, 593).
>
> [**ДОВІ́РЕНІСТЬ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovirenistj), ності, жін.
>
> Документ, що дає кому-небудь право діяти від
>   імені особи, яка видала його; доручення. Для виконання від імені
>   довірителя дій, що повинні безпосередньо встановлювати права і
>   обов'язки довірителя, довірений повинен мати письмову довіреність або
>   уповноваження (Цивільний кодекс УРСР, 1950, 47); — Отож, як дали мені
>   ту довіреність, я й почав клопотаться, од нижчих судів аж до вищих
>   (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 230).

Чи не є **довіреність** русизмом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Відповідь на це питання можна знайти на сайті [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/):

> **доручення** — дія за значенням доручати; договір, за яким одна сторона (повірений) зобов’язується вчинити від імені та за рахунок
>   другої сторони (довірителя) певні юридичні дії;
>
> **довіреність** — документ, що видається однією особою іншій особі для представництва перед третіми особами.

Приклади:

> Керівник дав мені **доручення** скласти звіт.
>
> Батько видав мені **довіреність** на керування автомобілем.

На сайті [Закон Біснес](https://zib.com.ua/ua/13361-dovirenist_chi_doruchennya_scho_neobhidno_mati_povirenomu_dl.html) також є стаття присвячена цьому питанню:

> ...Але основним нормативним актом у питанні визначення правових понять
>   слід вважати ЦК, який також є найбільш виваженим та послідовним у
>   цьому питанні. Кодекс однозначно визначає документом, що видається
>   однією особою іншій особі для представництва перед третіми особами,
>   саме **довіреність** (стст.95, 207, 243, 244, 246 та інші).
>
> **Доручення**, за нормами ЦК, має іншу правову природу (гл.68) — це
>   договір, за яким одна сторона (повірений) зобов’язується вчинити від
>   імені та за рахунок другої сторони (довірителя) певні юридичні дії. На
>   його підставі може бути видана **довіреність**.